# SQL to merge records based on multiple rules

Tags: sql, merge, rules

Below is the table data

```
AccountID PolicyNumber State Policy_Expiration_Dt VehicleTypeCode
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
80102 100 CA 21-12-2017 MC
80102 101 CA 21-12-2017 TR
80102   102 CA 21-12-2017 PP
80103 104 IL 14-12-2017 SO
80103 105 IL 14-12-2017 PP
```

Rules are:

1. For an account, merge policies having same expiration date
2. For an account, merge polices having same state
3. Pick the latest policy on each account for merging
4. Merge polices, having vehicle types below 
   a. MC & TR (If one policy is having MC, other having TR, then merge)
   b. PP (PP cannot be merged with any other type)
   c. SO (SO cannot be merged with any other type)

The output should be

```
AccountID PolicyNumber State Policy_Expiration_Dt VehicleTypeCode
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
80102 101 CA 21-12-2017 MC
80102 102 CA 21-12-2017 PP
80103 104 IL 14-12-2017 SO
80103 105 IL 14-12-2017 PP
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and any errors you are getting as a result of your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Try someting like this:

```
--------- CREATING EXAMPLE
CREATE TABLE #Something (
    AccountID INT
    ,PolicyNumber INT
    ,[State] CHAR(2)
    ,Policy_Expiration_Dt DATE
    ,VehicleTypeCode CHAR(2)
    )

INSERT INTO #Something
SELECT 80102,100,'CA','12-21-2017','MC'
UNION ALL SELECT 80102,101,'CA','12-21-2017','TR'
UNION ALL SELECT 80102,102,'CA','12-21-2017','PP'
UNION ALL SELECT 80103,104,'IL','12-14-2017','SO'
UNION ALL SELECT 80103,105,'IL','12-14-2017','PP'
---------END

SELECT a.AccountID
    ,a.Policy_Expiration_Dt
    ,a.[state]
    ,a.VehicleTypeCode
FROM (
    SELECT AccountID
        ,Policy_Expiration_Dt
        ,[state]
        ,CASE 
            WHEN VehicleTypeCode = 'TR'
                THEN 'MC'
            ELSE VehicleTypeCode
            END AS 'VehicleTypeCode'
    FROM #Something
    ) a
GROUP BY a.AccountID
    ,a.Policy_Expiration_Dt
    ,a.[state]
    ,a.VehicleTypeCode
```